# Is there a way to have Plot draw points on a function where the function is undefined as circles as in textbooks?

Tags: graphics, plotting

A very common feature of graphs of functions used throughout textbooks are simple indications, such as open circles, of the points at which a function is undefined. Is there a way to do this in Mathematica?

I understand that I can use `Epilog` (or `Prolog`, or other explicit drawing graphics functions) to "manually" draw these elements, but us there a way to automatically do this, or at least return the coordinates of such points for use as arguments to `Epilog`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By using [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html) and [`ExclusionsStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExclusionsStyle.html) like this

```
Plot[1/Sin[π x], {x, -3, 3},
  Exclusions -> Sin[π x] == 0, 
  ExclusionsStyle -> {Thin, Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]}
]
```

you can define the location of the discontinuities and the style for poles and discontinuity boundaries, respectively.

[image: Exclusionsstyle example image]

Also the [Wolfram Blog, March 2011](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/03/14/mathematica-qa-excluding-points-from-plots/) has more examples on this topic.

Comment: Why won't this work with `Sin[x]/x, {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> {0}`?

Comment: actually, i don't know. But in this case you can get a more consistent result by specifying the points to be excluded by an implicit equation: `Exclusions -> Sin[\[Pi] x]==0`. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: In that case I would use `Exclusions->x == 0`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - note that an exclusion is not necessary if you use `Sinc[x]` rather than `Sin[x]/x`.

Comment: @BobHanlon: Yes, but that's not the question.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `ExclusionsStyle` option to control how Mathematica renders regions excluded from the Plot.

**Edit**
Doing something like `ExclusionsStyle -> {None, {{Black, PointSize[Large]}}}` will put a large point at the excluded points. For example, modifying a function from the help documentation:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As near as I can tell, that simply changes how that segment of the graph is drawn (e.g. by omitting a single pixel in the figure), and provides no way to "exaggerate" the relevant points so they can be clearly seen.

Comment: I've updated with another option. The second entry in that options list sets the boundary style for the exclusion.