# Graphics plot of point using unfilled circle

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'd like to be able to place points on a plot using `Graphics[{Point[{a,b}],....}]` but have the plot symbol be an unfilled circle. I've looked around but can't find any way of doing this. Is there one? Thanks.

After reading the first response, perhaps I should add a bit more.  I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
p1 = Plot[x^2,{x,-3,3}]
p2 = Graphics[Style[Point[{0,0}],PointSize[Large]]
Show[p1,p2]
```

but with an unfilled circle instead of a dot.

The solution proposed in the first answer falls short in two ways: first, the unfilled circle does not properly hide graphics elements underneath it; second, the circle will appear as an ellipse, not a circle, in the (likely) event that the underlying graphic does not have aspect ratio 1.

The application here is for plotting piecewise discontinuous functions and showing clearly which endpoint at a jump discontinuity holds the value at the point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The purpose of the circles is to mark discontinuities, but if I understand you correctly you don't want exactly the same as in [this linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6/245) where the `ExclusionsStyle` option is discussed. You want the circles to sit only on one side of a discontinuity to indicate which side holds the value.

I'll compare that to the `ExclusionsStyle` method here. If you *do* use that option, it is possible to replace the default `Point` markers by anything you want using a replacement rule after the plot has been drawn:

```
With[{pointSize = .1},
 Plot[
   Floor[x], {x, -3, 3}, Background -> LightGray,
   ExclusionsStyle -> {None, {}}] /. Point[x_] :> Map[
    Inset[
      Graphics[
       {EdgeForm[Black], Cyan, Disk[]}
       ],
      #, Automatic, pointSize] &,
    x
    ]
 ]
```

[image: ExclusionsStyle]

So what I did here is to specify a dummy `ExclusionsStyle` with an empty list `{}` where the point style directive would normally go, just to make Mathematica draw `Point`s at the discontinuities in the first place.

Then I replace every occurrence of `Point` by an `Inset` containing the desired outlined disk (I colored it cyan for clarity here). The `Inset` is positioned where the `Point` coordinates would have been. The `Map` is used to take into account the fact that `Point` has a whole list of coordinates as its argument, and a new `Inset` has to replace each of these.

As I said, this may not be what you need because it marks *both* sides of the discontinuity equally.

An alternative would be to *not* use `ExclusionsStyle`, as you already suggest in the question. But instead of using `Graphics` to make the points, I would suggest to use `ListPlot`. Not only is it specially designed to do just such point sets, but moreover it is relatively straightforward to pass it arbitrary symbols or graphics as markers for the points:

```
With[{markerSize = .03},
 Show[
  Plot[Floor[x], {x, -3, 3},
   PlotStyle -> Thick],
  ListPlot[
   Table[{i, i}, {i, -3, 3}],
   PlotMarkers -> {
     Graphics[
      {EdgeForm[Black],
       Yellow, Disk[]}
      ], markerSize
     }
   ],
  Background -> LightGray
  ]
 ]
```

[image: ListPlot]

Here, the `Table` contains the points I want to mark, and that allows me to exclude one side of each discontinuity. Here I chose a yellow disk for clarity.

**Edit**

By using `ListPlot` with the points collected in a `Table`, one also has the flexibility to add differently styled points to mark the two sides of a discontinuity separately - something which is much harder to do within the framework of `ExclusionsStyle`:

```
With[{markerSize = .03}, Show[
  Plot[Floor[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Thick],
  ListPlot[{
    Table[{i, i}, {i, -3, 3}],
    Table[{i + 1, i}, {i, -3, 3}]},
   PlotMarkers -> {
     {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, Disk[]}], markerSize},
     {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Red, Disk[]}], markerSize}
     }
   ],
  Background -> LightGray]
 ]
```

[image: Better exclusion marking]

Answer (score 15):

You could do this by drawing the point twice, with different styles and sizes:

```
p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}];
p2 = Graphics[{{PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}, White, 
    PointSize[Medium], Point[{0, 0}]}];
Show[p1, p2, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

[image]

(I also moved the axes to the back, since they were drawing on top of the point.)

If you have several points, you can replace `{0,0}` with a list of them.

Comment: this works great! But where is the Method-> option documented? I can't find it, nor can I find any reference to "AxesInFront" in the in-product docs.

Comment: I don't think `AxesInFront` is documented anywhere, although it has been discussed on MathGroup in the past.

Answer (score 11):

> [**Update regarding edit**: As Brian B points out, the center of the SmallCircle is not exactly where one would expect it, so, for accuracy, one needs to Offset the text.
>   Compare

`Graphics[{Black, 
  Table[Text[Style["\[SmallCircle]", 48], 
    Offset[{0, -4}, {0, 0}]], {50}]}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> 1]`

> with

`Graphics[{Black, 
  Table[Text[Style["\[SmallCircle]", 48], {0, 0}], {50}]}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> 1]`.
]

> This "solution" is admittedly a bit sloppy, given that the value of the offset will depend on the font size in question.

---

**Edit**: **use `Text["\[SmallCircle], {a,b}]` for `Point[{a,b}]`**

Here's another try altogether, with different `AspectRatios`.  (Use a smaller font size than 28, if you find the circles too large.)

```
Graphics[{Black, Table[Text[
   Style["\[SmallCircle]", 28], {RandomReal[{-35, 35}], 
    RandomReal[{-35, 35}]}], {50}]}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True,
    PlotRange -> 35]
Graphics[{Black, Table[Text[
   Style["\[SmallCircle]", 28], {RandomReal[{-35, 35}], 
   RandomReal[{-35, 35}]}], {50}]}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 35]
```

[image: aspect ratios]

---

Earlier answer (possibly to be erased later?)

`Scaled` will keep the circles to the size you set, regardless of the PlotRange.

```
Graphics[Table[
 Circle[{RandomReal[{-5, 5}], RandomReal[{-5, 5}]}, Scaled[.005]], {50}], 
 Axes -> True,      PlotRange -> 5]
Graphics[Table[Circle[{RandomReal[{-35, 35}], RandomReal[{-35, 35}]}, Scaled[.005]],    
  {50}], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 35]
```

[image: two plots]

Comment: Sure, but that places a circle, and then I have to worry about scaling the thing properly, and the circle gets scaled according to the aspect ratio, which looks silly. Isn't there a style for points that says to use an empty circle?

Comment: Use the radius to set the size. See the picture.

Comment: I didn't know about Scaled. Thanks. However, I don't think this addresses the issues I [now, after an edit] raise in the original post. I guess the simple answer to my original question is "no, there's not", which is unfortunate.

Comment: You could also use `Offset` to create circles with a fixed radius, that doesn't scale with the graphic.

Comment: @rogerl  The update handles the `AspectRatio` issue you raised.

Comment: One could use `Inset[]` instead of `Text[]` as well.

Comment: @J.M. Yes. For some reason, I never think to use `Inset`.

Comment: Note that with `Text["\[SmallCircle]",...]` the center of the circle is not the proper point position.

Comment: @BrianB You are absolutely right.  I hadn't noticed this. With Offset this can be corrected but the workaround will likely depend on the font size being used. See update.

Comment: @BrianB - you can see this point displacement here too:  `Show[ListPlot[{{{8, 8}}, {{10, 10}}}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 40}], 
 ListPlot[{{{8, 8}}, {{10, 10}}}, PlotStyle -> Directive[White]], 
 AspectRatio -> 0.5, AxesOrigin -> {9, 9}, 
 PlotRange -> {{9, 13}, {9, 13}}, ImageSize -> 200]`

Comment: One could also use `\[EmptyCircle]` as a marker, which is a bit larger.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the `CirclePoint` primitive from David Park's Presentations add-on, http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html. For the original example:

```
Draw2D[{Draw[x^2, {x, -3, 3}],
        Thick, CirclePoint[{0,0}, 5, Black, White]},
       AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True]
```