# Specifying the size of open circle PlotMarkers in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I would like to use `ListPlot` to plot some points.  I would like the `PlotMarkers` to be open circles.  I can use `PlotMarkers -> Graphics[Circle[]]`, as in the following example, but the circles are too large.  Is there a way that I can specify the size of open circles to use in `PlotMarkers`?  Thanks for your time.

```
myData = {{0, 3.0}, {10, 3.1}, {20, 3.2}, {30, 3.0}, {40, 3.0}, {90, 3.0}};

ListPlot[myData, PlotRange -> {{-1, 101}, {2.9, 3.3}}, Joined -> True,
  Mesh -> Full, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
  PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[]}]]
```

[image: PlotMarkers]

Comment: `PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[]},ImageSize->10]`

Comment: Similar question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5770/graphics-plot-of-point-using-unfilled-circle

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`PlotMarker`s are rendered as insets to the graphics so you need to set a small image size in your graphics plot marker:

```
ListPlot[myData, PlotRange -> {{-1, 101}, {2.9, 3.3}}, Joined -> True,
  Mesh -> Full, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 10]]
```

[image]

Because plot markers are insets you may find that if you have a large number of points the graphic rendering is noticeably slow -- particular if the plot is made dynamic. In that case you can try and use primitives directly to get some speed improvements. This example hasn't quite worked out as planned because I've made an elipse rather than a circle for reasons not immediately clear (but probably obvious to someone else who might like to point out the error).

```
ListLinePlot[myData, PlotRange -> {{-1, 101}, {2.9, 3.3}}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Circle[#, Scaled[.01]] & /@ myData}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

it appears that `AspectRatio` is messing up the scaling but this can be fixed:

```
ListLinePlot[myData, PlotRange -> {{-1, 101}, {2.9, 3.3}}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 Epilog -> {Red, Thick, 
   Disk[#, Scaled[{0.02, 0.02*GoldenRatio}]] & /@ myData}]
```

[image]

...some random shapes:

```
ListLinePlot[myData, PlotRange -> {{-1, 101}, {2.9, 3.3}}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 Epilog -> {Red, Thick, 
   Polygon[{Scaled[{0.003, 0.01}, #], Scaled[{-0.03, 0.03}, #], 
       Scaled[{-0.03, -0.03}, #], Scaled[{0.02, -0.05}, #]}] & /@ 
    myData}]
```

[image]

...with the qualifier that you would go down this path if you have a large data set and plot markers (insets) are slowing things down.

Answer (score 5):

I repeatedly recommend using graphics primitives for the sake of performance, and in many cases simplicity or at least predictability.  I therefore support Mike's use of `Epilog`.  There is however a simpler method to render circles rather than ellipses: `Offset`.  This also produces a fixed-size "point" which may or may not be desired.

```
myData = {{0, 3.0}, {10, 3.1}, {20, 3.2}, {30, 3.0}, {40, 3.0}, {90, 3.0}};

ListLinePlot[myData,
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 101}, {2.9, 3.3}},
 Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick],
 Epilog -> {Red, Thick, Circle[#, Offset @ 5] & /@ myData}
]
```

[image]

`Offset` also works within `PlotMarkers` if you prefer to use the canonical method:

```
PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, Offset @ 5]}]
```

Answer (score 4):

What about the "Empty Circle" in the special characters menu. Go to Insert_Special Characters_Symbols to find it or type esc_eci_esc.

Comment: Font based markers have [alignment issues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/5)

Comment: I agree with Nguyen - the best solution is to simply use:  PlotMarkers -> "\[EmptyCircle]" ... \[EmptyCircle] with a backslash before ... site is dropping the backslash ... Works like a charm. Even better, you can adjust the size of the circle by simply selecting it with the mouse, and changing the font size. Same goes for changing the colour: just select the circle and change the colour to something that suits you. The end result is the neatest and shortest code.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment, so I'd just like to expand on the difference between Mike Honeychurch's and Nguyen Van Falk's answers.  Using graphics (like Mike) is slow if you have many points on the graph.  This is a reason to use mere characters (like Nguyen).  However, as veteran "rm -rf" pointed out in the comments to Nguyen's post, there can be some minor alignment issues due to the way fonts are rendered which are not very easy to fix in an a robust way.

Therefore, the best idea is to use characters when you need to plot quickly, and use slow graphics when you need something beautiful.  To choose a character, bring up the Special Characters panel from the Palette menu.

Answer (score 2):

Often `PlotMarkers` may not align exactly the way you expect.
An alternate to `ListPlot` is to construct the plot using `Graphics` primitives.

```
    myData = {{0, 3.0}, {10, 3.1}, {20, 3.2}, {30, 3.0}, {40, 3.0}, {90, 
        3.0}};

    Manipulate[
     Graphics[{{Blue, Line[myData]},
       {Red, GeometricTransformation[Circle[{0, 0}, Offset[{size, size}]],
          myData]}},
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 101}, {2.9, 3.3}}, Frame -> True, 
      PlotRangeClipping -> True, AspectRatio -> 1],
     {size, 5, 15}]
```

I first saw `GeometricTransformation` used for this purpose as an answer to a question on this site, but I can't seem to locate it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with malaligned `PlotMarkers` doesn't exist anymore. Here we use them with a size of `26` and see, that they nicely align with the red mesh points.

[How to input EmptyCircle](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/EmptyCircle.html)

[Shapes and Icons](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ShapesIconsAndRelatedCharacters.html)

```
list =
  {{0, 3.0}, {10, 3.1}, {20, 3.2}, {30, 3.0}, {40, 3.0}, {90, 3.0}};

ListPlot[list,
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 101}, {2.9, 3.3}},
 Joined -> True,
 Mesh -> Full,
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotRangePadding -> Automatic,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick],
 PlotMarkers -> Style["\[EmptyCircle]", 26, Blue]]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to control the thickness of the shape when using this method?

Comment: `PlotMarkers -> Style["\[EmptyCircle]", 26, Blue, Thickness[0.001]]` doesn't show any effect. But you can change the size: `12` instead of `26` for example.

Comment: Right but that means there is only one parameter to change (and not one for the radius and one for the thickness as would be preferable).

Comment: The issue still exists with Mma version 13.2.1. Indeed, if we make the radius of the blue circles only slightly larger than the radius of the red bullets, we can clearly see that the two are not concentric.