# Specifying plot markers (filled diamonds or squares)

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I can plot my list data and I can use of [specifying circle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/specifying-the-size-of-open-circle-plotmarkers-in-listplot)  to show my plot-markers. I used of *Mr.Wizard* comments on that page. But I don't know how can I fill the circles of those plot-markers with another color same as green or blue. As well as I don't know how can I create plot-markers with the shape of diamond or square (filled with another color or empty)! Is it possible to tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84857)?

Comment: that is so complete, unfortunately I haven't seen that. Do I close my question? It seems to be duplicate!

Comment: I'll put it on hold for now. If you have something not covered by that dupe, just edit your question.

Comment: Also a duplicate: [(56155)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56155/121)