# Plotmarker Option Cancels Plotstyle Option inside ListPlot

Tags: plotting, options, visualization

I have four lists of points, in my scenario they are very close to each other so I generate them by:

```
 list[1] = {{10, 20}, {400, 500}, {450, 602}, {580, 700}, {700, 
830}, {810, 920}}

 For[i = 2, i <= 4, i++,

  list[i] = list[1] + Table[{RandomReal[{-30, 30}], 0}, {i, 1, 6}]
    ]
```

Now when I listplot, I want the pointsize large so I do so in the plotstyle option:

```
ListPlot[Table[list[i], {i, 1, 4}], PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02]}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 500]
```

And everything comes out fine. However if I add the plotmarker option, either before or after the plotstyle option, it reduces the pointsize back to standard:

```
ListPlot[Table[list[i], {i, 1, 4}],PlotMarkers->Automatic, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02]}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Anyone know why that happens? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure but is it because `PlotMakers` is an inset to `Graphics`?http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/specifying-the-size-of-open-circle-plotmarkers-in-listplot

Comment: @MMM the default `PlotMarkers` are actually font glyphs - so in your answer you are (I believe) specifying a font size for them.  That's why most of the answers on here about `PlotMarkers` say to use an actual graphics primitive instead.

Comment: @JasonB. I see, that clears it up thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comment**

I don't know why it happens but you can adjust the size inside `PlotMakers`

```
 ListPlot[Table[list[i], {i, 1, 4}], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 500]
```