# Change size of plotmarkers inside listplot

Tags: graphics, visualization, size

I have a listplot whose plotmarkers I want to change the size of, to no avail.

Using what I see in the related post: [Specifying the size of open circle PlotMarkers in ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/specifying-the-size-of-open-circle-plotmarkers-in-listplot)

I get

```
 ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Red, Thick, Text["\[EmptySquare]"]}, 
     ImageSize -> 10], 
    Graphics[{Red, Thick, Text["\[Beta]"]}, ImageSize -> 10], 
    Graphics[{Red, Thick, Text["\[Alpha]"]}, ImageSize -> 10]}]
```

I cannot get that text to appear larger, whether I put it as a Style option inside the Text function or outside the Graphics. Any ideas? This seems too convoluted too, there has to be a smarter way of specifying what I want each plotmarker to be and what size I want for each plotmarker. That ImageSize option at the end of graphics doesn't do anything either. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: `Text` does not scale with `ImageSize`. That's the core of your issue. If you wanted to you could [get the word as a `Graphics` object](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88378/38205). Then it would scale with `ImageSize`.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot get that text to appear larger

This seems to work, no need for `ImageSize` nor Graphics actually, since your are using text for markers.

```
p[t_String] := Style[Text[t], {Red, Thick, 16}];

ListPlot[{{1,2,3,5,8},{2,3,6,9,10},{4,5,7,10,12}},
       PlotMarkers->{p["\[EmptySquare]"],p["\[Beta]"],p["\[Alpha]"]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
markers = First[First[ImportString[ExportString[
    Style[#, Italic, FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Times"], "PDF"], 
    "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]] & /@ {"□", "β", "α"};

ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> (Graphics[{Red, #}, ImageSize -> 10] & /@ markers)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> (Graphics[{Red, #}, ImageSize -> 15] & /@ markers)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]