# Is there any way to reveal a removable singularity in a plot?

Tags: plotting

Let's say we have a function $f(x)=\dfrac{2^x-2}{x-1}$. The graph of the function in *Mathematica* looks like this:

[image: plot of the function]

The function in question is obviously not continuous at $x=1$, but that doesn't show in the plot.

Is there an option to make *Mathematica* draw a hole at those points where a function is discontinuous, and if so, can I make this the default option?

Comment: If you define it to be equal to its limit, it is in fact continuous in 1.  The left and right limits exist and are equal.

Comment: You could tell MMA manually where it is also

`Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> {x == 1}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Disk[], PointSize -> 0.015}]`

Comment: `FunctionDomain` can be useful to try to detect points like these.  Generally, I don't think there's a good automatic *and reliable* way to detect such points though.

Comment: @Julian Thanks. That works, I guess. Any possibility there is an automatic way to do this?

Comment: @Szabolcs Only if you define it that way. But f(1) is not defined and so it's not part of the domain. So technically the function is not continuous at x=1.

Comment: @Cristopher "But f(1) is not defined" <-- it is not a good idea to treat Mathematica as a mathematician. Computer algebra systems will readily simplify things such as `((x - 1) (x - 2))/(x - 1)` and won't care about the fact that technically that function should be undefined at `x==1`.  Trying to handle these details would make them much too impractical and probably slow.  The conclusion is: it is up to *you* do decide whether you consider that function defined at x==1 or not, in the strict mathematical sense, and keep this in mind during symbolic manipulations.  Mathematica *will* ignore ...

Comment: ... that single point when it gets the chance to for the sake of practicality and simplicity.  But for this specific (and similar) cases, did you look at `FunctionDomain` that I suggested?

Comment: You could also use `Solve[Denominator[f[x]] == 0, x]`

Comment: Closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65624/12

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes I was aware of the existence of `FunctionDomain` . I was just wondering if there was an automatic way to do it but I've read your answer to the question in the link and it seems it's not possible. I now know there are practical reasons for that. Thank you for your comments and for the link.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Can your function be used to *automatically* mark the singularity that the OP describes?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It has some (perhaps typical symbolic-algebra) limitations, and you have to wrap the function in `Piecewise`, an oversight on my part.  But it will handle the OP's example automatically (if wrapped in `Piecewise`): http://i.stack.imgur.com/BRhMD.png

Comment: @MichaelE2 If you were to update your answer to handle this case natively without the manual addition of piecewise we might consider this question "already answered?"

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OK, updated with this OP's example included.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: [(6)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6), [(5770)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5770), [(11361)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11361)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard After some thought, I decide to vote to close as a duplicate of (39445).  You may, if you feel it is appropriate and are able, add either of (6) or (5770), if you feel it's appropriate; (11361) seems not quite close enough.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Looks like *you* forgot about the gold badge this time.  No matter, it's a good close, and thanks for finding and linking the other posts.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I remembered, and that's why I left the message.  I took your previous comment as an implicit agreement.  But when I do use the gold badge, I like to leave a note in case someone wants to respond.  I don't know -- can I reopen with one vote what I closed?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Okay, I was confused because I missed "and are able" which I am not.  I really wish there was a way to for moderators (and now gold badge holders) to mark more than one duplicate.  Anyway yes, you had my agreement.  I *think* you can reopen with one vote as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can combine parts of @Julian comment and @Szabolcs comment in the original post to have it marked automatically.

```
f[x_] := (2^x - 2)/(x - 1)

Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, 
 Exclusions -> {Reduce[! FunctionDomain[f[x], x]]}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Disk[], PointSize -> 0.015`}]
```

[image]

The inequalities that are returned by `FunctionDomain` negated to get the region not in the function's domain. The `Reduce` is used to combine inequalities where needed. `Exclusions` prevents points in the region from being plotted and `ExclusionsStyle` marks the points.

Hope this helps.

### **Update**

Try it with `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[h[x], {x, -10, 10}, 
  Exclusions -> {Quiet@Reduce[! FunctionDomain[h[x], x]]}, 
  ExclusionsStyle -> {Disk[], PointSize -> 0.015`}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, Automatic}],
 {{c, 1}, -9.5, 9.5},
 Initialization :> {h[x_] := (2^x - 2)/(x - c);},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c}]
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much :) Thanks everyone who commented, too.

Comment: Just a comment on `ExclusionsStyle -> {Disk[], PointSize -> 0.015}`: `Disk[]` doesn't do anything here, this might as well be `ExclusionsStyle -> {None, PointSize -> 0.015}`.  The first items sets the style of the inside of the exclusion and the second one sets the boundaries, check e.g. `Plot[HeavisideTheta[x - 1], {x, 0, 2}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Green, Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]}]`.  Here the inside is infinitely small so it's not visible.

Comment: Now tweak the style to draw a hollow circle in the same color as the graph, instead of a solid black dot, and you'll have a +1 from this Mathematica newbie. :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen See the answer, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5779, by Jens for the solution you request.